# Weight of 2D shape

Tags: analysis, volume

I want to compute a weight of the yellow object on the picture.
The density of the object is a function $$p(x,y)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$

[image]

I want to compute it using volume of the yellow object and average value of a density function. (volume * average density)
Is it possible to compute it that way?

Lot of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Sure. Let your yellow region be $Y$. We want
$$\iint_Y \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\,dy\,dx.$$
To evaluate, it is natural to switch to polar coordinates. We get
$$\int_1^3\int_0^\pi  \cos\theta\,d\theta\,dr.$$

Comment: Yes,it works. But I want to compute it using volume of yellow object what is 4PI. Like that: 4Pi * average density = X  So my question is: How can I compute an average density of function, but only in the yellow shape. Thanks

Comment: To compute the average density, we find the mass and divide by $4\pi$. Same calculation, apart from division then multiplication by $4\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

As average density is mass/volume, then yes.

So you just have to integrate the density over the yellow region.

$\int_r^R \int_0^\pi sin(\theta) dr d\theta$